# How to count number of cells in a single column that met the target per the corresponding target on that row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**[Goal]**

I want to be able to count the number of cells in a single column that met the corresponding target of that row. Here is an example [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wNQUoih5EJ2pLw8TtP-PMbn-AaKiKXBicB8IL96mASU/edit?resourcekey=0-PX6j92VLRqyJKu_b8BEZLg#gid=752523414) where you can check what I'm trying to do.

**[Investigation]**

I understand that if we use an IFS statement along with AND and OR per target, then we can achieve the result, but it's not sophisticated. And if I were to add or remove a row, then I would have to fix the formula every time so that the new or unnecessary targets are being considered. In addition, I have to take into consideration of every single scenario where a combination of rows that met and didn't meet the target, which is going to be very difficult.

For example, this is an extremely summed up version, however, it would look like this except 100 times longer.

```html
IFS(AND(F2>=$D$2,
F3>=$D$3,
F4>=D4,
F5>=D5,
F6<=D6,
F7>=D7,
F8>=D8,
F9>=D9
```

So if there's a way where the system could check each cells to see if it's meeting the target percentage per corresponding row and also not including hyphens ("-") as part of the counting methodology.

Comment: In this very particular scenario I'd say the easiest way out would be to go with a script or add-on that simply counts the colored cells (green here) in a range and gives you the count.

Answer (score 1):

to count cells in F column being equal it greater than D you could use something like this:

```
=SUM(MAP(D2:D,F2:F,LAMBDA(d,f,IF(f="",0,IF(f>=d,1,0)))))
```

But I don't know exactly what do you mean by `and also not including hyphens ("-") as part of the counting methodolog`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in formulas so I don't know how unoptimized or overcomplicated this may be, but this formula worked for me:

```
=COUNTIF(MAP(MAP(E2:E13, LAMBDA(inp, ISNUMBER(inp))), MAP($D2:$D13, E2:E13, LAMBDA(target, metric, IF(target>0.2,IF(metric>=target, TRUE, FALSE), IF(metric<=target, TRUE, FALSE)))), LAMBDA(x, y, IF(AND(x,y),TRUE, FALSE))), TRUE)
```

Based on your sample sheet I pasted it on E14 and dragged it to the right. The result is:

[image]

#### Explanation:

First I'm getting a `TRUE/FALSE` array to figure out which cells are hyphens using `ISNUMBER()`. Numeric values will return `TRUE`.

```
MAP(E2:E13, LAMBDA(input, ISNUMBER(input))
```

Next I compare each column with your defined targets in the D column to figure out if the target is being met. Note that this is tricky because some of your metrics have to be over the threshold while the others have to be under the threshold. Since all the metrics that have to be under the threshold are less than 5% I set it as `target > 0.2` for 20% just in case, but make sure to **define the threshold** as needed. This returns another `TRUE/FALSE` array.

```
MAP($D2:$D13, E2:E13, LAMBDA(target, metric, IF(target>0.2,IF(metric>=target, TRUE, FALSE), IF(metric<=target, TRUE, FALSE))))
```

Then just wrap both of the above parts and compare the `TRUE/FALSE` arrays. When both are `TRUE` it means that the value is not a hyphen AND it meets the criteria.

```
MAP(<Part 1>, <Part 2>, LAMBDA(x, y, IF(AND(x,y),TRUE, FALSE)))
```

Lastly you just need to wrap everything in a `COUNTIF` to count all `TRUE` values.

```
=COUNTIF(<All of the above>, TRUE)
```

Note that you still have to define the criteria range and the column range manually (see the parts with `$D2:D13` and `E2:E13`). You could try `$D2:$D` and `E2:E` so you won't have to modify them, but you would have to place the counts at the top of the table or to the right, since the count will include itself and you will have recursion issues.